# Are there any circumstances under which ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor would completely stop working?

Tags: java, multithreading

We are running a Java server app that is using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to manage some work. There are multiple instances running, for different types of work, but each instance only uses one thread. It's not important why this is as there's really no way around it. What we noticed on the production server is that one of these instances stopped working at some point, completely and silently. Restarting the server brought it back again, but the problem isn't solved.

I know that using `scheduleAtFixedRate` will stop if the task throws an exception at some point, but this isn't the case here. We had a recurrent task that simply stopped executing, and new tasks that used the schedule() method and still didn't execute. I presume that the thread it was using died and didn't start again.

My question is, are there any circumstances under which this could happen? Is there anything I should look out for?

Comment: Maybe if all the threads in the pool hang?

Comment: also, is there a remote possibility that the recurrent task failed silently (i.e the exception was swallowed)?

Comment: This seems pretty broad, seeing how you haven't provided code. I wouldn't doubt there are many reasons for it stopping completely and silently; one I can think of right off that bat is an exception is thrown and swallowed. Apparently this question is acceptable, seeing the upvotes, but akking if some unknown problem could cause something to stop working isn't going to render you the best results. At least show how you are attempting to do what you are doing

Comment: Generate a thread dump to determine what the threads are doing.

Comment: You should catch all of your exceptions and log them. Without seeing the log file with the stack trace it is impossible to know what caused the crash.

Comment: The question is rather general because I suspect this is either a bug in the library, or there's something about this class that I'm missing. The exceptions that are not caught in the task, are logged in the afterExecute method that I've overwritten. But there is no exception to speak of in the logs. And in any case, this isn't about a recurrent task that stopped working. New tasks that were scheduled did not get executed either.

Comment: So far I think the thread hanging is the most likely explanation.

Comment: Also, this happened on a production server once, after it was running fine with several days of uptime. A restart got rid of it and I can't actually reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the simplest explanation is the answer: all threads hang.

In my case the cause of this seems to be HTTP requests that never timeout. This can happen in certain situations and I am yet to find a good solution for the problem. I think the best option is to implement a timeout on the scheduled task itself to make sure we avoid any issues.